# OP name not highlighted in new mobile view

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web

In the new mobile view, I noticed that the OP's name is no longer highlighted in comments.

[image]

Browser is Chrome 50.0.2661.89 running on Android 6.0.0.  Not sure if this is a bug or an intentional design decision, but we can see the OP's name highlighted again?